# variation custom stock status linking to parent

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set up some custom stock statues as per the discussion here on this thread
[WooCommerce - Custom stock status and variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51929752/woocommerce-custom-stock-status-and-variable-products)

however a problem I'm encountering is with variations. Even if I have all the variations set to a custom status of "made to order" the parent just puts it as out of stock. (if I switch it back to simple product to test) Then on the front end it says out of stock when just using $product->get_stock_status(); Is there a way to either link custom stock statuses to an instock status or a hook I need to dive into to include a custom status condition as in stock? Thank you